# Python Cannot Run NoseTest due to CreateProcess Error 87

Tags: windows, python-2.7, nose, nosetests

I am trying to help someone get setup running nose tests. They are running into an error I have never seen before. A google search seems to be yielding results for Java, but not Python.

Below is a screenshot of the error:

[image]

Any ideas on how to correct this error?
I have tried uninstalling and re-installing Python. I have verified that the settings are correct as well as the parameters for the nose test. The PATH variables for Python are likewise correct.

Not sure what is going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying and failing to run the test from the terminal, I was able to determine that the PATH variables were incorrect after all. I fixed them, and then logged off and back on again, and the issue is fixed.